# Android: auto scrolling down the EditTextView for chat apps

Tags: android, chat, android-edittext, autoscroll

Thank you for looking,
I am creating a chat application. It works for the most part.
The only thing I have a problem with is the scrolling.
I use **EditText** to publish the new message from the server.

by method

```
msg = msg + "\n" + newMsg
EditText.setText(msg)
```

I need to make the new text that is under the old text visible as soon as it comes.

So I think best way is to **auto scroll down** to the bottom as soon as the view is updated.

Is there an easy way to do that? like in **layout** maybe?

Thanks again!

code for layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<Button
android:id="@+id/sendButton"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
android:text="send"
/>
    <EditText
android:id="@+id/msgBox"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" 
android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/sendButton"
android:gravity="left"
android:longClickable="false"
/>
<EditText  
android:id="@+id/chatBox"
android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:editable="false"
android:layout_above="@+id/msgBox"
android:scrollbars="vertical" 
android:gravity="left|top" 
android:isScrollContainer="true" 
android:cursorVisible="false" 
android:longClickable="false" 
android:clickable="false"
android:autoLink="all"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

A solution is to send a seperate UI message via post.
That will definitely work.
After you setText/append text to your TextView inside the ScrollView
 update the ScrollView via the post(Runnable) method like the code below:

```
messageView.append(blabla);      
scroller.post(new Runnable() { 
                public void run() { 
                    scroller.smoothScrollTo(0, messageView.getBottom());
                } 
            });
```

Comment: This works to scroll ALL the way to the bottom ! Use Jignesh's XML layout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5101448/android-auto-scrolling-down-the-edittextview-for-chat-apps/5101616#5101616 and then SenorCarbone's code above.

Answer (score 11):

I think best way to do this use TextView with scroller rather than EditText because once message print user can't edit it. Try something like this, This is beautiful way to print message

```
<ScrollView android:id="@+id/scroller"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"

        android:background="#FFFFFF">
        <TextView android:id="@+id/messageView"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:paddingBottom="8dip" android:background="#ffffff"
            android:textColor="#000000" />
    </ScrollView>
```

And to scroll automatically down call this method after pushing message to view

```
private void scrollDown() {
        scroller.smoothScrollTo(0, messageView.getBottom());  
}
```

Here scroller is ScrollView and messageView is TextView

You can also print message with differnt color using HTML like

```
messageView.append(Html.fromHtml("<font color='green'><b>("+date+") "+ username +":</b></font><br/>"+ message+"<br/>", null, null));
```

Comment: it is very nice to do that but i use EditText because i like the box look. I also made it not editable nor clickable. I have been trying to get this to work with your solution but it seems my layout is a relative layout and that does not go well with the rest.  or maybe i was not doing it right. please take a look at my layout. thank you!

Comment: I was stupid! I should have looked closely, it was the append instead of setText that makes it work!! Now it wont go down to the last one but the second last.. any comment?

Comment: Thanks for accept ans, you can also append smiles using HTML.formHTML()

Comment: Try. scroller.smoothScrollTo(0, messageView.getBottom()+5000);

Answer (score 1):

Try this method:
[Programatically scrolling an EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256678/programatically-scrolling-an-edittext)