# The text should appear from the beginning of the editText, not the end

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-scroll

I want the `EditText` to automatically scroll to the beginning, when focus is lost.

Comment: Please eloberate and post code. If possible add images.

Comment: did you tried ?? SO is not for code generating its help when you stuck so first try and show some code

Answer (score 1):

- You can add a focus listener on your edittext using this.

  **[Event for Handling the Focus of the EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7397391/event-for-handling-the-focus-of-the-edittext)**
- In that listener, you can scroll your edittext programmatically using this.

  **[Programatically scrolling an EditText](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2256678/programatically-scrolling-an-edittext)**

Hope this helps.
Good luck.